# Extract Image from Instagram using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, instagram

I'm trying to extract an image from Instagram using Nokogiri. I've tried so many things that I don't even think it's a good idea to show what I've done so far.

I'm starting with:

```
image_url = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://instagram.com/p/g3mXJ1p109/'))
```

And I've noticed the picture on Instagram.com is in the following div:

```
<div class="Image iLoaded iWithTransition Frame" src="http://distilleryimage9.ak.instagram.com/b711daf4508c11e385ff1234c61f9f0f_8.jpg"></div>
```

Ok, just one thing I've tried:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(open(pic)).css('body script').children.first
```

and it gives me this:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::CDATA:0x767c904 "\nwindow._csrf_token = '88b78a58e333056bcc67e338f06ce786';\nwindow._jscalls = [\n\n['bluebar', 'init', []],\n\n['framework/config', 'init', [{staticRoot: '//d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net/bluebar/89c8068'}]],\n\n [\"lib\\/fullpage\\/transitions\",\"bootstrap\",[{\"componentName\":null,\"moduleName\":\"lib\\/ui\\/media\\/DesktopPPage\",\"props\":{\"viewer\":null,\"shortcode\":\"g3mXJ1p109\",\"prerelease\":false,\"staticRoot\":\"\\/\\/d36xtkk24g8jdx.cloudfront.net\\/bluebar\\/89c8068\",\"media\":{\"code\":\"g3mXJ1p109\",\"comments\":{\"nodes\":[]},\"date\":1384805104.0,\"likes\":{\"count\":0,\"viewer_has_liked\":false,\"nodes\":[]},\"owner\":{\"username\":\"marunbai\",\"requested_by_viewer\":false,\"profile_pic_url\":\"http:\\/\\/images.ak.instagram.com\\/profiles\\/anonymousUser.jpg\",\"id\":\"549577518\",\"followed_by_viewer\":false},\"is_video\":false,\"id\":\"592110592901733693\",\"display_src\":\"http:\\/\\/distilleryimage9.ak.instagram.com\\/b711daf4508c11e385ff1234c61f9f0f_8.jpg\"}}}]],\n\n];\n">
```

Comment: It is not clear what you need help with. Are you just trying to get the div element using nokogiri or maybe the image's src?

Comment: Just the image source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokogiri cannot evaluate the JavaScript. As a result, if you look at the HTML that Nokogiri sees, the `div` tag you see will not be there.

However, the page does contain a meta-element with the image source. You can extract the desired value from there:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://instagram.com/p/g3mXJ1p109/'))

p doc.at_css('meta[property="og:image"]')['content']
#=> "http://distilleryimage9.ak.instagram.com/b711daf4508c11e385ff1234c61f9f0f_8.jpg"
```